# New to Python - operator //

Tags: python

I have found some code which should work, but don't.. What am I doing wrong / is missing?

Source: [How to find table like structure in image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829874/how-to-find-table-like-structure-in-image)

```
def find_table_in_boxes(boxes, cell_threshold=10, min_columns=2):
    for box in boxes:
        (x, y, w, h) = box
        print(box)
        col_key = x // cell_threshold

if __name__ == '__main__':
    text_boxes = [
        {
            'x': 123,
            'y': 512,
            'w': 100,
            'h': 150
        },
        {
            'x': 500,
            'y': 512,
            'w': 100,
            'h': 150
        }
    ]
    cells = find_table_in_boxes(text_boxes)
```

## error

```
# python test.py
{'x': 123, 'w': 100, 'y': 512, 'h': 150}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 22, in <module>
    cells = find_table_in_boxes(text_boxes)
  File "test.py", line 5, in find_table_in_boxes
    col_key = x // cell_threshold
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: What is the code suppose to do?

Comment: Read the error -- it says `unsupported operand types(s) for //: 'str' and 'int'`. That means you're trying to divide a string and an integer.

Comment: do `print(x, y, w, h)` to see what you're doing in there.

Comment: `(x, y, w, h) = box` assigns the keys of `box`, that is, strings `'x'`, `'y'`, etc., to the variables `x,y,w,h`.

Comment: change `(x, y, w, h) = box` to `(x, y, w, h) = box["x"], box["y"], box["w"], box["h"]`

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey isn't both vars int? They looks like integers to me when looking in the code

Comment: @clarkk Obviosly not, as DYZ already explained.

Comment: You are trying to floor division on an int and a string

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.  "Looking at the code" is not a particularly detailed or accurate debugging tactic.  Been there, done that, made a quilt from all the t-shirts ...

Comment: It's unclear why you thought that *would* work; what made you think a dictionary would be the same as a bounding rectangle? You need to *adapt* code you find for your specific needs (the change you *did* make, from assigning to a list of names to assigning to a tuple of names, doesn't make any difference). Also this question is generally of a very disappointing standard for a user with your rep.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's telling you `x` is a string. It comes from `boxes` which comes from `text_boxes`. You cannot unpack dictionary values with:

```
    (x, y, w, h) = box
```

Try this instead:

```
x = box["x"]
y = box["y"]
w = box["w"]
h = box["h"]
```

Another option is:

```
def _find_table_in_box(cell_threshold, x, y, w, h):
    print(x, y, w, h)
    col_key = x // cell_threshold


def find_table_in_boxes(boxes, cell_threshold=10, min_columns=2):
    for box in boxes:
        _find_table_in_box(cell_threshold, **box)
```

Comment: ...or `x = int(box["x"])`, etc.

Comment: Another, more compact option would be `(x, y, w, h) = (box[i] for i in 'xywh')`

Comment: @barny For what purpose?

Comment: Or just *use `box['x']`*, as that's the only value they access.

Comment: You *can* unpack the dictionary with `(x, y, w, h) = box`, you're just getting the keys (`str`), not the values (`int`)

Comment: To convert str to int, why else?

Comment: Yes you can unpack the dictionary with `(x, y, w, h) = box`. You mean to say "you don't get automatic string-to-int conversion (either of keys, values, or both) when unpacking a dict (from JSON or wherever)". But you could manually implement it with a factory function, wrapping `json.load/loads`, etc.