# OpenCV Assertion failed: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S)

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I have found the following code on [this website](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/how-to-break-a-captcha-system-in-15-minutes-with-machine-learning-dbebb035a710):

```
import os
import os.path
import cv2
import glob
import imutils
CAPTCHA_IMAGE_FOLDER = "generated_captcha_images"
OUTPUT_FOLDER = "extracted_letter_images"


# Get a list of all the captcha images we need to process
captcha_image_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(CAPTCHA_IMAGE_FOLDER, "*"))
counts = {}

# loop over the image paths
for (i, captcha_image_file) in enumerate(captcha_image_files):
    print("[INFO] processing image {}/{}".format(i + 1, len(captcha_image_files)))

    # Since the filename contains the captcha text (i.e. "2A2X.png" has the text "2A2X"),
    # grab the base filename as the text
    filename = os.path.basename(captcha_image_file)
    captcha_correct_text = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]

    # Load the image and convert it to grayscale
    image = cv2.imread(captcha_image_file)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Add some extra padding around the image
    gray = cv2.copyMakeBorder(gray, 8, 8, 8, 8, cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

    # threshold the image (convert it to pure black and white)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    # find the contours (continuous blobs of pixels) the image
    contours = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Hack for compatibility with different OpenCV versions
    contours = contours[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else contours[1]

    letter_image_regions = []

    # Now we can loop through each of the four contours and extract the letter
    # inside of each one
    for contour in contours:
        # Get the rectangle that contains the contour
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

        # Compare the width and height of the contour to detect letters that
        # are conjoined into one chunk
        if w / h > 1.25:
            # This contour is too wide to be a single letter!
            # Split it in half into two letter regions!
            half_width = int(w / 2)
            letter_image_regions.append((x, y, half_width, h))
            letter_image_regions.append((x + half_width, y, half_width, h))
        else:
            # This is a normal letter by itself
            letter_image_regions.append((x, y, w, h))

    # If we found more or less than 4 letters in the captcha, our letter extraction
    # didn't work correcly. Skip the image instead of saving bad training data!
    if len(letter_image_regions) != 4:
        continue

    # Sort the detected letter images based on the x coordinate to make sure
    # we are processing them from left-to-right so we match the right image
    # with the right letter
    letter_image_regions = sorted(letter_image_regions, key=lambda x: x[0])

    # Save out each letter as a single image
    for letter_bounding_box, letter_text in zip(letter_image_regions, captcha_correct_text):
        # Grab the coordinates of the letter in the image
        x, y, w, h = letter_bounding_box

        # Extract the letter from the original image with a 2-pixel margin around the edge
        letter_image = gray[y - 2:y + h + 2, x - 2:x + w + 2]

        # Get the folder to save the image in
        save_path = os.path.join(OUTPUT_FOLDER, letter_text)

        # if the output directory does not exist, create it
        if not os.path.exists(save_path):
            os.makedirs(save_path)

        # write the letter image to a file
        count = counts.get(letter_text, 1)
        p = os.path.join(save_path, "{}.png".format(str(count).zfill(6)))
        cv2.imwrite(p, letter_image)

        # increment the count for the current key
        counts[letter_text] = count + 1
```

When I try to run the code I get the following error:

```
[INFO] processing image 1/9955
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extract_single_letters_from_captchas.py", line 47, in <module>
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:741: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'pointSetBoundingRect'
```

I've tried searching for a solution on StackOverflow, but I didn't find anything remotely similar.

---

EDIT (see comments):

- `type(contour[0])` = `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`
- `len(contour)` = `4`

Comment: Please, add `len(contour)` and `type(contour[0])`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply, I just updated my question.

Comment: Comment this line `contours = contours[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else contours[1]`

Comment: @BahramdunAdil Thanks for the quick reply, now it giving me the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extract_single_letters_from_captchas.py", line 49, in <module>
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'array'`

Comment: @Fozoro I updated my answer with some info on why this happened in case you're curious :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is doing the wrong thing:

```py
contours = contours[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else contours[1]
```

`imutils.is_cv2()` is returning `False` even though it should return `True`. If you don't mind to remove this dependency, change to:

```py
contours = contours[0]
```

---

I found out the reason. Probably, the tutorial you are following was published before OpenCV 4 was released. OpenCV 3 changed [`cv2.findContours(...)`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=find%20contours#cv2.findContours) to return `image, contours, hierarchy`, while [OpenCV 2's `cv2.findContours(...)`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#cv2.findContours) and [OpenCV 4's `cv2.findContours(...)`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) return `contours, hierarchy`. Therefore, before OpenCV 4, it was correct to say that if you use OpenCV 2 it should be `contours[0]` else `contours[1]`. If you still want to have this "compatibility", you can change to:

```py
contours = contours[1] if imutils.is_cv3() else contours[0]
```

Comment: @Fozoro glad to help, but now I'm curious why they changed this output on OpenCV 3 :) I'll let you know if I find something about it

Comment: @Fozoro I could not figure it out :( The change happened 5 months ago (here's the [commit](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/8eb987e39351fa1e28c1d2919c86cc6483b6b414#diff-70b5dcc8e14faa52a44dc890f926d9a5)), but there is no pull request or issue linked to it. Sometimes things just change, I guess :)

Comment: Alternatively, you can change to `imutils.is_cv2(or_better=True)`. You will then get `True` if you are using opencv4

Comment: @NikO'Lai but this would not address the issue that only OpenCV 3 has a different return format

Answer (score 6):

In OpenCV4, cv2.findContours has only 2 return values.
***Contours being the FIRST value***

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Note that I added underscore to let go of the other return value of ***hierarchy***

Answer (score 4):

```
 (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour.astype(np.int))
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Answer (score 1):

This is because of opencv-python version 4.0.0. If you want to fix this without changing your code then downgrade opencv-python to version 3.4.9.31

- Uninstall opencv-python

  > pip uninstall opencv-python
- Install opencv-python==3.4.9.31

  > pip install opencv-python==3.4.9.31

If facing issue with function 'pointSetBoundingRect', you need to install 'opencv-python-headless'

```
pip install opencv-python-headless==3.4.9.31
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the same code in following way:

```
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

and my code worked. I think previously it was returning 2 variables now we have to unpack into three variables. If this doesn't work try the following:

```
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

this should work.

For more information, you can visit the OpenCV documentation page: https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason lays in findContours().

In OpenCV version 3, we wrote:

```
_, contours, _ = cv.findContours()
```

In OpenCV version 4, we change to:

```
contours, _ = cv.findContours()
```

Use either that fix the problem.

Or, we can stabilize our OpenCV version with these commands, suppose that you had `anaconda` installed.

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv=4.1.0 

pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Answer (score -1):

【OpenCV 3 changed cv2.findContours(...) to return image, contours, hierarchy】
This content is very helpful for me. I adda new variable to the front and I fix all the error..

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59640566/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead