# Error -215:Assertion Failed using openCV's projectpoints()

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I would like to compute the Jacobian of some object point coordinates with respect to the extrinsic and intrinsic parameters of a camera. To do so, I'm using `openCV`'s `projectPoints`, which returns the Jacobian as an optional argument.

Here is the `openCV` documentation on the function:

> imagePoints, jacobian =   cv.projectPoints(   objectPoints, rvec, tvec, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs[, imagePoints[, jacobian[, aspectRatio]]]    )

When I call `projectPoints(objectPoints, rvec, tvec, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs)`, I get this error:

> `cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /tmp/opencv-20200726-67088-i69mik/opencv-4.4.0/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp:3558: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_64F) in function 'projectPoints'`

I have read through this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734538/opencv-assertion-failed-215assertion-failed-npoints-0-depth-cv-32) as well as this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/opencv/comments/6s4jku/python_opencv_assertion_failed_npoints_0_depth_cv/), which both suggested checking the data types and sizes of the first argument being passed into `projectPoints`.

All of my variables are `ndarray`s and their sizes match the documentation requirements.
I have also read that it could be due to a problem with the actual coordinates of the points, meaning that the points don't fit in the image frame and so a solution cannot be computed, but I am unsure of how to fix that analytically. I am trying to simulate a set of object points seen by a camera in order to get the image points.
Is there any mathematical relationship that must be conserved between `objectPoints`, `rvec`, `tvec`, `cameraMatrix` and `distCoeffs`? If not, are there any typical / standard values that I could use as a starting point?

Here is my code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv
from numpy import shape, tile, matmul, zeros, transpose

# SIMULATE SOME POINTS
# Rotation Matrix
R = np.eye(3)
# Translation vector
t = np.array([[1],[0],[0]])
# Camera calibration matrix
K = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1]])
# World frame coordinates of the points 
Xw = np.array([[0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,0], [2,2,2,0], [3,3,3,0], [4,4,4,0], [5,5,5,0]]).T
Xw = Xw.astype('float64')
# [R|t]
Rt = np.concatenate((R,t), axis=1)
# Distortion coefficients
dist_coeffs = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

# GET THE JACOBIAN TO SOLVE THE LEAST SQUARES EQUATION FOR t
# Transpose Xw to fit projectPoints()
Xw = Xw[:3,:].T
# Compute the Jacobian
_, H = cv2.projectPoints(Xw, R, t, K, dist_coeffs)
```

*Note - I am using Python 3.8.5 and OpenCV 4.4.0, with numpy 1.19.1.*

Edited to add runnable code.

Edited to remove dead code in snippet.

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/89414/cv2.projectPoints) you should call `projectPoints` with 5 parameters

Comment: Can you please add runnable code into your example here that reproduces the error? For example you can just define the numpy arrays that you pass in here, and verify they give you the same error.

Comment: Thanks @alkasm. I did.

Comment: The docs state "A 3xN/Nx3 1-channel or 1xN/Nx1 3-channel" but your points have length 4, not 3. Is that your issue? Also, you're not using your `xp` variable, is that intentional?

Comment: @alkasm thanks for catching that, that worked! With a couple forcing arguments to be floats as well. About xp, I accidentally left that line in this snippet. I edited my question to reflect that change.