# OpenCV boundingRect() function throws unexpected error

Tags: python, image-processing

My goal is to have a working script for identifying a table on an image. I stumbled upon this posts answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51756462/10434683
He is exactly doing what I need. However if I run this code I get an error that looks like this:

[image]

It seems like the error is caused by the boundingRect() function. Ive looked up the docs, however didnt find anything useful.

The following is the function where boundingRect() is used...

```py
def find_text_boxes(pre, min_text_height_limit=6, max_text_height_limit=40):
    # Looking for the text spots contours
    contours = cv2.findContours(pre, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = contours[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else contours[1]

    # Getting the texts bounding boxes based on the text size assumptions
    boxes = []
    for contour in contours:
        box = cv2.boundingRect(contour) #error
        h = box[3]

        if min_text_height_limit < h < max_text_height_limit:
            boxes.append(box)

    return boxes
```

Comment: According to the error, verify that the contour which raise the error is not empty.

Comment: Any ideas how to do that @LiorCohen

Comment: Use debug breakpoint

Comment: Please do not post any errors as images. Write it out as code instead.

Comment: Which version of OpenCV do you use in you program? OpenCV 3 version of `findContours` returns a tuple of `(img, contours, hierarchy)` and OpenCV 4 - `(contours, hierarchy)`. Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829874/how-to-find-table-like-structure-in-image/51756462 for reference.