# Extract table into csv from scanned PDF by using pytesseract python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-tesseract

I have different type of invoice files, I want to find table in each invoice file. I am able to convert scanned pdf to image by using 'pdf2jpg' method now i have to extract table from each invoices and write into csv file by using OCR pytesseract method. Please help.

Comment: You can't get that in pytesseract. Pytesseract is supposed to just extract all the text from a pdf file.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829874/how-to-find-table-like-structure-in-image) should be helpful for you.

Comment: Depending on how the pdf was made, you may be better off using pdf2txt directly, rather than converting to jpg and then trying ocr.  If the pdf was scanned from a paper invoice, that won't help, but if it was generated directly you can get the text without having to try to use ocr.

Comment: @Siddharth Prajosh I have already tried that shared link but didn't get relevant result. Please find below code that i am using -----------------------------------------------

Comment: @Siddharth i tried to use the code on shared link but now i am getting error as "AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'make_blob'". Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract table as text from the PDF using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47533875/how-to-extract-table-as-text-from-the-pdf-using-python)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this code will help you:

```
import pyautogui
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'

text = pytesseract.image_to_string('c:\\screenshot\\test.png')

f = open('c:\\screenshot\\csvfile_1.csv','w')
f.write(text)
f.close()
```

[image: Sample Image]