# How to find table like structure in image by Open CV

Tags: python, ocr, opencv

[image: Table on image]

I have not bordered table like on picture .

I tried to use example from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829874/how-to-find-table-like-structure-in-image)
I have got this result

[image: Result image]

But I need something like this
[image: Needed result]

How I could tune Open CV to get needed result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieved by using `image_to_data` method of pytesseract.

You also need to know:

- [Pre-processing methods](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#image-processing)
- [Page-segmentation-modes](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method)

---

Steps:

- 1. Load the image in BGR mode and convert it to the gray-scale
- 2. Get region-of-interest areas
- 3. From each area, get the coordinates and draw rectangle.

Result:

[image]

Code:

---

```py
# Load the library
import cv2
import pytesseract

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("1Tksb.jpg")

# Convert to gry-scale
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# OCR detection
d = pytesseract.image_to_data(gry, config="--psm 6", output_type=pytesseract.Output.DICT)

# Get ROI part from the detection
n_boxes = len(d['level'])

# For each detected part
for i in range(n_boxes):

    # Get the localized region
    (x, y, w, h) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])

    # Draw rectangle to the detected region
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 1)

# Display
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

If you want to read you can use `image_to_string` method.