# How to slice an image by table border

Tags: image-processing, png

I have many png files like this:[image: image table]

I want to slice the image into 48 (=6x8) small image files for the 48 cells separated by the table borders. That is, I would like to have files `img11.png`, ..., `img68.png`, where `img11.png` contains the (1,1) "1.4x4x8" cell, `img12.png` the (1,2) "M/T" cell, `img13.png` the "550,000" cell, ..., `img68.png` the bottom right "641,500" cell.

I want to do it because I thought it would improve the performance of `tesseract`, which is not satisfactory because many of my image files have much poorer quality than shown above. Also, margins and sizes are diverse, and some images contain non-English characters and images.

Would there be software packages to detect the table borders and slice the image into m x n images? I am new in this area. I have read [How to find table like structure in image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829874/how-to-find-table-like-structure-in-image) but it's way beyond my ability. I am willing to learn, though.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: sum the rows, then sum the columns separately, the black lines should sum to zero, then detect the zero indices in the rows/columns summation, then you can split your image by the indices you have [x0, x1, ...], [y0, y1, ...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using R. Bilal's suggestion (thanks) led me to the following.

Step 1: Convert the image to grayscale.

```r
library(magick)
x <- image_read('https://i.stack.imgur.com/plBvs.png')
y <- image_convert(x, colorspace='Gray')
a <- as.integer(y[[1]])[,,1]
```

Step 2: Convert "dark" to 1 and "light" to 0.

```r
w <- ifelse(a>190, 0, 1)         # adjust 190
```

Step 3: Detect the horizontal and vertical lines.

```r
ypos <- which(rowMeans(w) > .95)  # adjust .95
xpos <- which(colMeans(w) > .95)  # adjust .95
```

Step 4: Crop the original image (`x`).

```r
xpos <- c(0,xpos, ncol(a))
ypos <- c(0,ypos, nrow(a))

outdir <- "cropped"
dir.create(outdir)
m <- 0
for (i in 1:(length(ypos)-1)) {
  dy <- ypos[i+1]-ypos[i]
  n <- 0
  if (dy < 16) next  # skip if too short
  m <- m+1
  for (j in 1:(length(xpos)-1)) {
    dx <- xpos[j+1]-xpos[j]
    if (dx < 16) next  # skip if too narrow
    n <- n+1
    geom <- sprintf("%dx%d+%d+%d", dx, dy, xpos[j], ypos[i])
    # cat(sprintf('%2d %2d: %s\n', m, n, geom))
    cropped <- image_crop(x, geom)
    outfile <- file.path(outdir, sprintf('%02d_%02d.png', m, n))
    image_write(cropped, outfile, format="png")
  }
}
```

The cropped (1,1) image is [image: image22].